# HTML Purifier setup - having trouble allowing Rich Text, only need the security side

Tags: security, yui, htmlpurifier, richtext

I'm trying to setup HTMLPurifier for my needs.  I have it up and running but straight out of the box it strips all formatting.  I tried delving through the documentation but that was an exercise in frustration.  Is there an easy configuration option that only implements the security aspect of the program and allows through all the rich text styling, etc.  I'm not exactly sure how the YUI RTE marks up its output for styling so simply going through and creating a whitelist might be quite time consuming and involve going through both the purifier documentation and the YUI documentation - all for a simple task.  Anyone have any premade configurations for this sort of thing or at least a point in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default HTML Purifier allows as much styling as possible that can be allowed securely. So you are probably seeing a different problem; my guess is magic quotes. You should var_dump the HTML right before it enters HTML Purifier and turn off magic quotes if there are extra backslashes.